# Help me with "let"

Tags: grammar

My friend wrote a sentence

> Let they love what they want to love

I think it should be "Let them ...."

Who's correct ?

I think I'm right because as much I know, after "let" it's an object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're exactly correct.
 "Let " calls for an objective form.

Answer (score 1):

This is an imperative sentence. It is command the hearer, the assumed "you", to let someone do something. "They/them" is the object of that action. So the idea is "you let them love". "Them" is the object form and so that is what should be used.

If you dropped the word "let", this would become a declarative sentences, saying what "they" are doing. "They love [whatever]". Then it would call for "they", because then "they" is the subject.